How to decode Message Compiled Instruction? for decodeTransferCheckedInstruction
I was using decodeTransferCheckedInstruction with legacy version but want to move to VersionedTransaction.
However, I can't find any alternative of decodeTransferCheckedInstructionfor versioned transaction (MessageCompiltedInstruction).
It's a simple transfer instruction and I want to get the transferred amount from instruction.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Since decodeTransferCheckedInstruction requires a TransactionInstruction to decode, we need to get from VersionedTransaction to one of those. Looking around, we have:

VersionedTransaction has a VersionedMessage
TransactionMessage.decompile takes a VersionedMessage and returns a TransactionMessage
TransactionMessage has an array of TransactionInstructions

So you simply need to use TransactionMessage.decompile on your transaction to extract the TransactionInstructions
